# What and all string operation is available in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am doing client side validation for entered date so what and all string operation jquery allows?

Comment: Javascript. It's **Javascript**! https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods_2

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is a javascript library which handles a number of things; string manipulation is not one of them.  There are plenty of regular javascript string handling functions.

For an overview of the available javascript string functions, take a look at
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp

Answer (score 1):

Can do a simple javascript but I myself like jquery and regular expressions

```
var date_regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$/;

$('form').submit(function(){
    if( $('input.text').val().match(date_regex) == null){
       return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

and this code date format mm/dd/yyyy